# Show that $\Phi(x)=x+f(x)$ is a diffeomorphism where $f$ is contracting

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I am given $f : R^n \to R^n$ and $\Phi(x)=x+f(x)$, and that $f$ is of class $C^k$ and contracting. I have to show that $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^k$.

I am able to show that $\Phi$ is bijective using that $f$ is contracting, so all that's left is to show that its inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ is differentiable of class $C^k$ too. My original thought was to use the Inverse Function Theorem for this, but this only gives us a class $C^k$ inverse locally. I'm not sure how to extend this to show that $\Phi$ is globally a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Your question is strange. If $\Phi^{-1}$ is $C^k$ locally, then it is $C^k$ globally.

Comment: So I guess using the Inverse Function Theorem like I have done is enough? What about my function $\Phi$ gives the local implies global fact that you have written?

Comment: 1) Yes it is enough. 2) I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Why is "If $\Phi^{-1}$ is $C^k$ locally, then it is $C^k$ globally." true?

Comment: $C^k$-regularity is a local notion. Think about how it is defined.